# chrome extension - injecting via content script a button which always appears on the page regardless the scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension app I'm building using react ts.

As the title suggests, what I'm trying to create  some sort of a 'Stop Recording' button, which is supposed to be injected via content script.

As it is a button which's task is to stop the recording of the screen, I need it to continuously be present to the user, regardless how much the user is scrolling or where is he navigating to in the web.

Any ideas on how could I perform such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this is quite easy, add into styles `position: 'fixed'`,
and make sure your styles are at no point getting override by a parents container.

For my case, my style was override by MaterialUI components, which I have overcome using `position: 'fixed !important'`.

Good luck to anyone facing this issue.